# Bootstrapping (aleatoric and epistemic) risk score uncertainty

Tags: classification, confidence-interval, bootstrap, prediction-interval, uncertainty

I am working on various risk score estimation problems. I assume individual subjects are associated with a *true risk*
$$r_i = f(x_i; \epsilon_i), \quad 0 \leq r_i \leq 1,$$
where $x_i$ is some available information about the subject and $\epsilon_i$ describes aleatoric uncertainty about the risk, which I assume to be *heteroskedastic*. (I.e., the distribution of $\epsilon_i$ varies as a function of $x_i$.)
Furthermore, we are given observations $y_i$ of the (binary) outcome:
$$y_i \sim \text{Ber}(r_i).$$

The canonical way of estimating such risk scores is, of course, to use a probability model (say, a logistic regression or xgboost model), perform (log loss) regression, and interpret the model output (which lies in $[0, 1]$) as the risk estimate $\hat{r}_i(x_i)$ of that subject (possibly applying calibration to ensure that the risk scores coincide with the observed incidence, i.e.,  $\hat{r}_i(x_i) \approx E[y_i \mid X=x_i]$).

What I am now interested in is **quantifying the uncertainty of individual risk estimates $\hat{r}_i(x_i)$** using a bootstrapping approach. This should include both aleatoric uncertainty (resulting from the action of $\epsilon_i$) and epistemic uncertainty (resulting from uncertainty about the learned model).

Things I have found so far but was unable to transfer to my setting:

- The classical theory for this question seems to fall under the umbrella term "interval estimation for a binomial proportion," see, e.g., [Brown et al. (2001)](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=10.1214%2Fss%2F1009213286). This includes things like Wald CIs etc., and there are also bootstrapping versions of these, see [Mantalos et al. (2008)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949650701749356) and [Wang and Hutson (2013)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4789773/). However, these all consider the setting where a *single* (population-level) proportion is to be estimated, not where the estimated proportion is a function of some covariates $x$. (I am also unsure whether they consider heteroscedastic aleatoric uncertainty, see my comment below on confidence intervals.)
- There is a branch of research that estimates *prediction intervals* using bootstrapping methods. This seems exactly like what I want to do (recall that [risk estimation is a regression problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22381/why-not-approach-classification-through-regression) and notice that I am not interested in *confidence intervals*, because [these do not cover aleatoric uncertainty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423325/confidence-intervals-for-predictions-from-logistic-regression/14424417#14424417)). However, the [methods I could find so far](https://saattrupdan.github.io/2020-03-01-bootstrap-prediction/) are based on resampling the *residuals* - and that does not seem feasible in my setting, because the "risk residuals" $r_i - \hat{r}_i$ are unobservable (since $r_i$ is unobservable).

What would be / is there a feasible bootstrapping approach to do what I want?

Note: this is a more specific follow-up question to [my earlier, broader question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/575182/131402).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I just elaborated on in [my answer to my original, broader question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/577871/131402), what I am asking for seems to be fundamentally impossible to do.